# Rastrear uso de funciones (de usuario) en PHP

Tags: php, function, tracking

Estoy programando una aplicación que ya tiene varios archivos y necesito de alguna manera saber en dónde fueron llamadas/usadas las funciones y clases que he definido.

Imagino algo como "`get_user_defined_function_used_in()`" (??) y que me tire un listado, array u objeto con los nombres de los archivos y la línea donde la función/clase fue llamada.

He leído acerca de [`register_tick_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) y aunque no entendí del todo su funcionamiento y usos, no veo cómo me podría servir`.

En lo posible preferiría evitar el uso de extensiones ajenas a PHP.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizá sea mejor usar [`debug_backtrace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.debug-backtrace.php), que sirve precisamente para *rastrear*. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1423157/5587982), hay varias respuestas con proposiciones interesantes. Sea como sea, decidas lo que decidas, te corresponde implementar el código y si tienes algún problema entonces te ayudaremos a resolver ese problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano no estoy buscando hacer el tracking de un error. Busco implementar alguna forma de poder saber en dónde fue usada cada función/clase (archivo y línea) entre todos los archivos que conforman la aplicación. Algo así como `get_included_files` pero para lo que dije.

Comment: No le veo mucho sentido a eso para hacer tracking de errores, ¿acaso no es eso lo que hace el log de errores? Yo implementé algo parecido a lo que quieres hacer aquí en un contexto muy distinto: tenía en una aplicación más o menos grande varios archivos desde los que llamaba a clases antiguas y quería saber desde dónde se estaban llamando a esas clases, entonces puse algo así como un log trace en las clases que me decía quienes las estaban llamando. Me fue muy útil para actualizar ese código antiguo, que programé en mis inicios en php, a lo bruto, sin usar manejo de rutas y demás.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero no quiero hacer ni un track de errores ni un log de errores, eso ya lo tengo. Quiero un listado de dónde usé las funciones y clases que definí. Claro, algo como ese "log trace" quiero hacer. Estaba pensando en un script que lea los archivos y busque las funciones/clases, si es que PHP no tiene ninguna función para eso (no la tiene, al menos por lo que he leído hasta ahora).

Comment: Entonces la pregunta no está planteada con claridad. Por tu último comentario se interpreta que lo que quieres es una lista de todas las funciones definidas en tus archivos ¿? Entonces, un código que encuentre la ruta de cada uno de tus archivos, combinado con [`token_get_all()`](https://www.php.net/token_get_all) podría ser la solución. Aclara la pregunta, pues en la redacción actual se entiende que quieres saber **desde dónde** están siendo llamadas las funciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finalmente conseguí una función que rastrea las llamadas a todas las funciones.

Esta función recibe dos parámetros:

- `$archivos`: Un array secuencial con los nombres de los archivos a escanear, incluyendo la ruta absoluta.
- `$funciones`: Un array con las funciones a buscar.

  ```
  function rastrear_funciones($archivos, $funciones) {
      $salida = array();
      $contador = 0;
      $stream = null;
      $linea = null;
      $patron = null;
      foreach($archivos as $archivo) {
          $contador = 0;
          $stream = fopen($archivo, 'r');
          while (!feof($stream)) {
              $linea = trim(fgets($stream));
              foreach($funciones as $funcion) {
                  $patron = '/(\b(?:function|new)\b\s*)?\b' . preg_quote($funcion) . '\s*\(/';
                  $coincidencia = preg_match($patron, $linea, $coincidencias);
                  if ($coincidencia) {
                      if (!array_key_exists(1, $coincidencias)) $salida[$funcion][] = $archivo.":".$contador;
                  }
              }
              unset($linea);
              $contador++;
          }
          fclose($stream);
      }
      return $salida;
  }
  ```

En mi caso, tengo las funciones definidas en un archivo y escribí una función que lee esas funciones y devuelve un array. Y para los archivos escribí una función que escanea recursivamente el directorio indicado y devuelve un array con todos los archivos encontrados.

**Nota**: He leído sobre la eficiencia del uso de memoria cuando se leen archivos y esta solución puede no ser eficiente para archivos "grandes" debido a la propia naturaleza de funcionamiento de la memoria RAM. En esos casos conviene usar la función `explode()` para generar un array con las líneas del archivo.

**Nota 2**: mi "problema" estaba en la expresión regular definida en `$patron`. Gracias al Pollo por la ayuda: [la respuesta esclarecedora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/587759/172993)

Comment: Alguien que le de formato porque no me lo toma... :?

Comment: listo, ahí está