# PHP REGEX Negative Lookbehind condicional

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular cuyo objetivo es buscar las llamadas a una función (y no funca como se espera). Las condiciones de la búsqueda son las siguientes:

- la palabra 'function' no debe preceder a `$funcion`
- entre 'function' y `$funcion` puede haber 1 o mas espacios en blanco
- delante de 'function' puede haber 1 o mas espacios en blanco, y 0 o mas caracteres
- después de `$funcion` puede haber 0 o mas espacios en blanco y DEBE haber un '('

La expresión que conseguí hasta ahora es ésta:

```
'/(\w\W){0,}\s{0,}(?<!function\s)\s{0,}('.$funcion.'){1}\s{0,}\(/'
```

Y la pruebo de la siguiente manera:

```
$html = null;
$funcion = "es_multi"; // llamada a buscar
$textos = array(
    "function es_multi()", // no
    "algo function es_multi(", // no
    "new es_multi(", // no debería aunque con la expresión actual está bien.
                    // Este es el condicional que me gustaría incluir: (?<!new\s).
    "\$es_multi", // no
    "es_multies_multi(", // no
    "es_multi es_multi(",  // no
    "es_multi(",  // si
    "es_multi()", // si
    "es_multi(\$param=valor)", // si
    "no_es_multi(",  // no
    "  function    es_multi  (" // no
);
$patron = "/(\w\W){0,}\s{0,}(?<!function\s)\s{0,}($funcion){1}\s{0,}\(/";
$coincidencia = null;

foreach($textos as $texto) {
    $coincidencia = preg_match($patron, $texto);
    $html .= "<p>$texto: ";
    if ($coincidencia === false) $html .= "error";
    elseif ($coincidencia == 1) $html .= "match";
    elseif ($coincidencia == 0) $html .= "matchn't";
    $html .= "</p>";
    $coincidencia = null;
}
echo $html;
```

Y este es el resultado que obtengo:

```
function es_multi(): matchn't // bien

algo function es_multi(: matchn't // bien

new es_multi(: match // bien (corregir)

$es_multi: matchn't // corregir para que pueda ser '(es_multi' o '{es_multi'

es_multies_multi(: matchn't // bien

es_multi es_multi(: match // bien

es_multi(: matchn't // mal. debería coincidir

es_multi(): matchn't // mal. debería coincidir

es_multi($param=valor): matchn't // mal. debería coincidir

no_es_multi(: matchn't // bien

function es_multi (: match // mal (este tiene múltiples espacios en blanco)
```

No sé qué me falta... he leído y probado pero no doy en la tecla.

Graceas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de verificar que no esté precedida por `function` es mucho más sencillo y eficiente intentar que coincida con eso, para luego excluirlas de los resultados.

```
'/(\b(?:function|new)\b\s*)?\b' . preg_quote($funcion) . '\s*\(/'
```

La primera parte que nos interesa filtrar está entre paréntesis.
Luego, sólo es cuestión de descartar los resultados que tuvieron una coincidencia en el grupo 1.

---

Cuando en una expresión regular usás paréntesis, se crea un **grupo** y todo el texto que haya coincidido con el primer grupo de paréntesis será devuelto en `$matches[1]`. En este caso, vamos a buscar todas las coincidencias que NO tengan ese grupo asignado.

Código:

```
<?php

$textos = array(
    "function es_multi()",
    "algo function es_multi(",
    "new es_multi(",
    "\$es_multi",
    "es_multies_multi(",
    "es_multi es_multi(",
    "es_multi(",
    "es_multi()",
    "es_multi(\$param=valor)",
    "no_es_multi(",
    "  function    es_multi  ("
);



$funcion = "es_multi";
$patron = '/(\b(?:function|new)\b\s*)?\b' . preg_quote($funcion) . '\s*\(/';

foreach($textos as $texto) {
    $coincidencia = preg_match($patron, $texto, $matches);
    
    if ($coincidencia) {
        // tiene el texto de $funcion
        if (array_key_exists(1, $matches)) {
            // pero coincidió el grupo 1, lo que está entre paréntesis
            // o sea, está precedida por function o new
            echo 'Descartado: ' . $texto . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            // OK, coincide!
            echo 'Coincide: ' . $texto . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No coincide: ' . $texto . PHP_EOL;
    }


}

?>
```

Resultado:

```
Descartado: function es_multi()
Descartado: algo function es_multi(
Descartado: new es_multi(
No coincide: $es_multi
No coincide: es_multies_multi(
Coincide: es_multi es_multi(
Coincide: es_multi(
Coincide: es_multi()
Coincide: es_multi($param=valor)
No coincide: no_es_multi(
Descartado:   function    es_multi  (
```

---

---

**Opción 2: sin código extra, incluyendo la condición dentro del regex**

Tenemos la opción de incluir dentro de la expresión regular a la verificación donde nos aseguramos de que no haya coincidido con el grupo 1. La contra es que hace que el patrón sea un poco más complicado de leer y entender nomás.

En el código usamos esta condición para descartar cuando coincide el grupo 1

```
if (array_key_exists(1, $matches)) {
```

esto lo podemos lograr con el patrón condicional que intenta diferentes expresiones de acuerdo a si se grabó una referencia para el grupo 1

```
(?(1) verdadero | falso )
```

en donde en la parte del `verdadero` tenemos que hacer que falle el intento de coincidencia (y el `falso` que es opcional no lo usamos)

```
(?(1)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))
```

Con `(*SKIP)` y `(*FAIL)` estamos usando [verbos de control](http://www.rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html) que hacen que el intento de coincidencia falle totalmente, y que la posición en la que va a intentar la próxima coincidencia avance hasta donde se encuentra actualmente cuando llegó a `(*SKIP)`... Y así logramos que ignore completamente a las funciones que están precedidas por `function` o `new`.

Regex:

```
$patron = '/(\b(?:function|new)\b\s*)?\b' . preg_quote($funcion) . '\s*\((?(1)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))/';
```

Código:

```
$funcion = "es_multi";
$patron = '/(\b(?:function|new)\b\s*)?\b' . preg_quote($funcion) . '\s*\((?(1)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))/';

foreach($textos as $texto) {
    if (preg_match($patron, $texto)) {
        // tiene el texto de $funcion
        // y no está precedida por function ni new
        echo 'Coincide: ' . $texto . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo 'No coincide: ' . $texto . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: He probado tu propuesta y cualquier cosa que tenga ` $funcion(` (hay un espacio en blanco delante de `$funcion`) lo filtra como válido. Ahora, no entiendo como haría ese filtrado del que hablas con la expresión...

Comment: No, no lo es. Pero `function $funcion(` da match y no debería. Lo mismo sucede con `algo function $funcion(` o con `[espacio]*n    function     $funcion      (`: son match's incorrectos. Por eso te preguntaba por el filtrado. Si no lo hace la expresión, lo debo hacer yo de alguna otra manera. Para eso hago una serie de `strpos()`.

Comment: Ahí agregué el código para que se entienda lo que decía (estaba algo apurado cuando te respondí :-)

Comment: Excelente! Ahora obtengo los resultados deseados y esperados. Gracias. Como añadidura dejo este link a una respuesta que aún no estando estrictamente relacionada a mi pregunta, explica cómo funciona el motor REGEX con lujo de detalles para el que le interese: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130368/172993

Comment: Ya que te interesa entender el funcionamiento del motor de regex, ahí agregué una 2da opción más complicada que hace todo sin el código extra para descartar coincidencias 

Comment: Fuaa! Todavía estoy con el patrón anterior... estoy con algunos `echo`s comprendiendo... pero me guardo esta respuesta!